# how use a for loop inside of filter function?

Tags: pyspark

I wanna filter a column of my dataframe based on some elements of a list. how I can do it with a for loop?

For example suppose I have `my_list=['ca','hg,'po]`, and I wanna filter `col1` based on this list. I can do following:

```
df.filter((df.col1=='ca')|( df.col1=='ca')|(df.col1=='ca'))
```

how I can use a for loop instead of writing each condition in a bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark's [isin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html) column function:

```
my_list = ['ca','hg','po']
df.filter(df.col1.isin(my_list))
```